# Mongodb sum after unwinding array of nested objects

Tags: mongodb, count, sum, aggregation

I am new to mongodb aggregations. Given the following collection:

```
[
  {
    "ft": 1,
    "pippo": 10,
    "pluto": 5,
    "detail": [
      {
        "ft": 1,
        "pippo": 1,
        "pluto": 2
      },
      {
        "ft": 2,
        "pippo": 1,
        "pluto": 2
      },
      {
        "ft": 1,
        "pippo": 1,
        "pluto": 2
      },
      {
        "ft": 3,
        "pippo": 1,
        "pluto": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ft": 2,
    "pippo": 4,
    "pluto": 3
  }, {
    "ft": 1,
    "pippo": 1,
    "pluto": 1
  }
]
```

I would like to calculate the sum of all items having "ft":1.
I have tried this aggregation after unwinding the items contained in the array:

```
[
  {
    '$unwind': '$detail'
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': '$ft', 
      'count': {
        '$sum': 1
      }, 
      'ft': {
        '$first': '$ft'
      }, 
      'pippo': {
        '$sum': '$pippo'
      }, 
      'pluto': {
        '$sum': '$pluto'
      }
    }
  }
]
```

And getting the following wrong result:

```
_id: 1,
count: 4,
pippo: 40,
pluto: 20
```

The correct result should be:

```
_id: 1,
count: 4, // all items having ft === 1
pippo: 13, // the sum of all pippo in all items where ft === 1
pluto: 10 // the sum of all pluto items where ft === 1
```

Comment: I think that your schema is wrong.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? What's wrong?

Comment: What is the difference between `detail` field and main documents?

Comment: The detail document can have other properties. You can cosider it as a child item.

Comment: I see that the `detail` field is having the same fields as the main document, then what's the point of making sub documents. It's useless and I think it's a bad schema. Such schemas will be difficult to query and maintain.

Comment: The schema is given. That's not the point of my question but thanks for your help.